# AWS Lambda log group not recreated after deletion

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I accidentally deleted a lambda log group in CloudWatch.

Now my lambda fails and I do not see the log group reappear in CloudWatch.

Is it supposed to be recreated automatically? How can I fix the situation?

I tried recreating the log group manually but it didn't receive any log.

Comment: It should be re-created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and redeploy the lambda.

Also, make sure it has permissions to write to CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

If the role configured in the lambda function has permissions to write to CloudWatch logs, then the lambda function will recreate the log groups upon execution. It may take up to a minute after the function has been invoked.

To resolve this issue, modify the role that is configured in the lambda function to include the "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" Policy. This is an AWS Managed policy that includes everything you need to write to CloudWatch Logs.

See this article and video walk through!
https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Write_To_CloudWatch_Logs_From_Lambda